# MySQL - Hard Query with Max, Datediff, Subquery, Distinct/Limit

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, max

In short: MySQL - I need to bring company that have been inactive for a while (or 365 days for the fiddle example).

How I check this? each company have at least a contact, who is related to an event, and each event have (many) subevents, in this last table I have the last date of activity, the days that considers that one company is on inactivity is decided for the user, I don't have problem to do this calculation

```
sql.Append("where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE(lastdate)) > " +days.ToString()+ "
```

The problem is, that this check ALL the subevents, so this not only check the last date, but every date... and this means, bad output.

I was thinking on subqueries to get or the max date on the subevent of a contact, or the max date of the subevent of a event.

Then with a friend we get close with sort of this, but the query is infinite.

```
select * from subevent se
where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE(
(select se2.dates from subevent se2 
where  se2.dates in 
(select max(se3.dates) 
from subevent se3 
where se.idev = se3.idev) 
group by se2.dates)));
```

I'm stuck and I would appreciate the help...

Tried group by, subquery and MAX (obviously max is necessary, but don't how where to apply...)

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wgSQGn7Z26tHnwm6nAaNSA/8

(On the Fiddle link, should only bring the companyname2 and companyname4)

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in the question* would help illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: on Fiddle link is that data, or u mean something else? sorry, im new, the desired result is only the company, in the example would be second and four company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation to get the last subevent date for each company.  Then filter using a `having` clause:

```
select c.idcomp
from contact c join
     events e
     on e.idcont = c.idcont join
     subevent se
     on se.idev = e.idev
group by c.idcomp
having max(se.date) < current_date - interval 365 day;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cCGpCV4wyW1toCXcWUHUu7/0) is a db-fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I run that on the fiddle and it returns the 4 firsts company's instead the 2 that should return, but I'll try to do something with that code

Comment: @Synystter . . . I added a db-fiddle.  The code works.  Your tables are messed up because you declared the dates as integers and don't have proper `date` constants.

Comment: hahaha, yes I was fixing everything after write the first comment. Thanks for the patience